# Changing z-index

Tags: css, position, z-index

I am trying to change the `z-index` of this image "title-image" to be behind the feature section like this:
[image]

So I made the position of it absolute and the position of the feature section relative and its `z-index:1;` as in the pic:
[image]

But I have this error "Expected BRACE at line 73, col 11." and it appears  like this:
[image]

not as I wish so what to do?
my code

```
.title-image {
   width: 60%;
   transform: rotate(25deg);
   position: absolute;
}

#features {
   padding: 7% 15%;
   background-color: #fff
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: You need to provide some code for us to identify the error. When its fixed, you'll  just need to add `overflow: hidden` on the feature section element

Comment: you can check with `overflow: hidden` in #features element?

Comment: I don’t understand what do you mean. I am actually  a beginner and this is the second time  I ask on this website  so I am not familiar with it yet

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the background-color: #fff I don't know what is telling you that you are missing a brace, but that would be one place so start by correcting that.

Comment: yes, I saw. thank you the problem is solved now  @AHaworth

Answer (score 0):

Remember z-index is basically an order of what stacks on top of what, so once positions are established, each stacking item needs to have a z index value (higher number stacks on top of lower numbers)

In addition, `overflow: hidden` for the title image once you have z-index values in place for each object.

Comment: Sorry, what is overflow: hidden?